# Simulate Ctrl+Down Arrow

Tags: vba, excel

Create a table and insert 2 rows of data and then insert 8 blank rows into the table

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
MsgBox Selection.row
```

returns row 3

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
```

returns row 11

The *End Method* is behaving differently how can I make it behave like the Selection version?
Edit: One more detail, ClearContents and then Insert the rows with VBA

Comment: Are the rows with data above or below the rows without data?

Comment: @cheezsteak the rows with data are on the top right below the header.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error.

Comment: @cheezsteak What row number is being returned?

Comment: Can't reproduce this, so perhaps you need to add some more details to your question - maybe specify exactly which ranges are filled or blank.

Comment: @TimWilliams What row number is being returned? I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: I get row 3 for both.

Comment: I get 2 in both cases, but I suspect my layout is not the same as yours, hence the need for more detail. For example, insert 8 blanks rows *where* in the table?  And my table has headers...  And when you say table do you mean Listobject?

Comment: It is based on "SELECTION".  I'm going to suggest we re-evaluate your intentions instead of trying to figure out why the select method doesn't work like the end method.  I would by reading this assume you have a value lower on the sheet with a space in it somewhere, to answer the question.

Comment: Try Clearing the Contents of all the fields and then adding fields in the VBA code BEFORE you do the comparison above.

Comment: @PJRosenburg I think I found out my problem the Table will not update the rows inserted even if I use DoEvents until the Sub is ending.

Comment: Would have helped to show your entire code up-front....

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry, had tunnel vision. The issue seems to be the table does not update until the sub ends no matter what I do.